# Can I align the desktop icons in a grid fashion, so that they are aligned vertically as well?

Tags: 11.04, icons

Now when you choose to keep the icons aligned on the desktop they only align horizontally in vertical columns, so that they cannot be placed outside of these columns. What they do not do is align vertically so that there is an even space vertically between all icons, you can even overlap them if you want to. How can I make my desktop behave as a grid? Shouldn't this be default in the Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer an issue for me since I've turned off that the desktop is handled by the file manager. Gives a much cleaner and less distracting experience.

Comment: Could you explain how you did that, please?

Comment: I did it with the help of Ubuntu-Tweak if i remember correctly